# Cant make simple WCF + gSOAP stack

Tags: c++, wcf, gsoap

I'm trying to make a simple communication WCF-C++.
WCF application is a simple implementation of calculator (add, sub, div, mul). Ther eis no any additional dependencies or files in project.
Then i made a gSOAP application and added generated proxy with a such options:

```
wsdl2h.exe -o %FILE%.h %WSDL%
soapcpp2 -C -L -w -i -j %FILE%.h -I ../../import/ -d"%OUTPUT_PATH%"
```

I compiled my project and now experiencing a such problem:

WCF response:

```
Bad Request - Invalid Verb
------------------------------------
HTTP Error 400. The request verb is invalid.
```

gSOAP error:

```
Error 3 fault: SOAP-ENV:Client[no subcode]
"Validation constraint violation: tag name or namespace mismatch in element 'HTML'"
Detail: [no detail]
```

Comment: Did you check the namespaces expected from the gSoap Server against the namespaces realized by your WCF-C++ client?

Comment: yes. 1. it don't work with <xml> header. also it don't work with \r\t. and it don't work with default namespace SOAP-ENV, which defined by specification too..

Comment: where can i get namespace name, expected by server? and how can i change it?

Comment: May be asking your question in the [gSoap yahoo group](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/gsoap/) gives better results.